# Exibir vídeo com JavaCV usando applet

Tags: java, aplicação-web, câmera

Estou utilizando um applet que exibe imagem de uma câmera de segurança através do JavaCV.

Executando sozinho, o applet exibe o vídeo perfeitamente.

Quando eu rodo o applet na minha aplicação web, ele até renderiza os componentes swing, mas não é exibido vídeo, nem imagem. Estou utilizando o código exibido na resposta a [esta pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18544781/how-to-create-a-java-applet-accessing-webcam-using-javacv.)